Need verification of coefficients in Spherical Harmonic
I made up an example which lacks azimuthal symmetry and exists on the boundary and outside of the sphere:
$$\nabla^2 u(r,\theta,\phi) = 0; 0<\theta<\pi,0<\phi<2\pi \\ u(a,\theta,\phi) = a^2\sin(\theta)^2\sin(\phi)^2$$
The complex representation of the solution is: $u_{lm}(r,\theta,\phi) = \sum_{l = 0}^\infty \sum_{m = -l}^l [A_{lm}r^l + B_{lm}r^{-(l+1)}]P_l^m\cos(\theta)e^{im\phi}$. Since our solution only exists on and outside the boundary of the sphere, then it is expected that as $r\rightarrow \infty$, the eigenfunction $R(r)$ is expected to go to 0, so $R(r) = 0 = A_{lm}r$ and therefore $A_{lm} = 0$, and $R(r) = B_{lm}r^{-(l+1)}$, and our solution then becomes:
$$u_{lm}(r,\theta,\phi) = \sum_{l = 0}^\infty \sum_{m = -l}^l B_{lm}r^{-(l+1)}P_l^m\cos(\theta)e^{im\phi};|m|<l$$, and leveraging orthogonality
$$\tag{1}B_{l'm'} = r^{l'+1}h_{l'}^{m'}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi u(r,\theta,\phi)[Y_{l'}^{m'}(\theta,\phi)]^*\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi$$
where $Y_l^m(\theta,\phi) = h_l^m P_l^m(cos(\theta))e^{im\phi}$, $h_l^m = (-1)^m\sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{4\pi}\frac{(l-m)!}{(l+m)!}},[Y_l^m]^* = h_l^{-m}P_l^{-m}(\cos(\theta))e^{-im\phi}$, and $P_l^{-m} = (-1)^m\frac{(l-m)!}{(l+m)!}P_l^m(\cos(\theta))$.
I understand that the trick here is to identify solutions such that the inner product is nonzero, and the first step for taking advantage of this is to begin by creating a complex sum representation of our Boundary Condition:
$$u_{lm}(a,\theta,\phi) = u_{lm}(\theta),\phi) = a^2\sin(\theta)^2\sin(\phi)^2 = \sum_{l = 0}^\infty \sum_{m = -l}^l B_{lm}a^{-(l+1)}P_l^m\cos(\theta)e^{im\phi}$$
Which can be rewritten into its associated form as:
$$a^2(1-x^2)\Big(\frac{e^0}{\color{red}{2}} - \frac{1}{4}e^{-2i\phi} - \frac{1}{4}e^{2i\phi}\Big) = \sum_{l = 0}^\infty \sum_{m = -l}^l B_{lm}a^{-(l+1)}P_l^m\cos(\theta)e^{im\phi} = \Big(a^{-1}B_0 P_0(x)e^0 + a^{-2}B_{1,-1}P_1^{-1}(x)e^{-i\phi} + a^{-2}B_1P_1(x)e^{0} + a^{-2}B_{1,1}P_1^1(x)e^{i\phi} + a^{-3}B_{2,-2}P_2^{-2}(x)e^{-2i\phi} + a^{-3}B_{2,-1}P_2^{-1}(x) + a^{-3}B_2P_2(x)e^{-i\phi} + a^{-3}B_{2,1}P_2^1(x)e^{i\phi} + a^{-3}B_{2,2}P_2^2(x)e^{2i\phi} + ...\Big)$$
From observation of the left-hand side: there are no $x^1$ terms meaning $l \ne 1$, we have $x^0$ and $x^2$ so we'll assume $l=0,2$, and the values of m in the complex exponential $e^{im\phi}$ are $m = 0,\pm 2$. To make things a bit cleaner, we'll also absorb the $a^{-(l+1)}$ and $a^2$ into the $B_l^m$ constants to make $C_{lm} = a^{-2}a^{-(l+1)}B_{lm}$.
$$\tag{2} (1-x^2)\Big(\frac{e^0}{2} - \frac{1}{4}e^{-2i\phi} - \frac{1}{4}e^{2i\phi}\Big) = C_0 P_0(x)e^0 + C_{2,-2}P_2^2(x)e^{-2i\phi} + C_2P_2(x)e^0 + C_{2,2}P_2^2(x)e^{2i\phi}$$
Rewriting the LHS in terms of Legendre polynomials gives:
$$\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2} = C_0 + C_2\frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1) = C_0 - \frac{C_2}{2} + \frac{3C_2}{2}x^2 \rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{3C_2}{2}x^2 = 0; \frac{1}{2} - C_0 + \frac{C_2}{2} = 0 \rightarrow C_2 = -\frac{1}{3}; \frac{1}{2} - C_0 -\frac{1}{6} = 0 \rightarrow C_0 = \frac{1}{3}}$$
$$\tag{3} \color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}P_0e^0 - \color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}P_2(x)e^0 - 2P_2^{-2}(x)e^{-2i\phi} - \frac{1}{12}P_2^2e^{2i\phi} = C_0 P_0(x)e^0 + C_{2,-2}P_2^{-2}(x)e^{-2i\phi} + C_2P_2(x)e^0 + C_{2,2}P_2^2(x)e^{2i\phi}$$
$$B_0 = \color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}a^3 \\ B_2 = -\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}a^5 \\ B_{2,-2} = -2a^5 \\ B_{2,2} = -\frac{1}{12}a^5$$
Are these correct?

The result: $$u(r,\theta,\phi) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}\frac{a^3}{r} - \color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}a^2\Big(\frac{a}{r}\Big)^3\frac{1}{2}(3\cos(\theta)^2-1) - 2a^2\Big(\frac{a}{r}\Big)^3\frac{1}{8}\sin(\theta)^2 e^{-2i\phi} \\ - \frac{1}{12}a^2 \Big(\frac{a}{r}\Big)^3 3\sin(\theta)^2 e^{2i\phi}$$
EDIT: After looking through the math a couple times, I spotted a mistake in my complex representation of $\sin(\phi)^2$, I made fixes in red and added the work for identifying $C_0$ and $C_2$.
